# Saving a GIF from a URL

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, format

I want to save a GIF driven from an internet address.
When I request the file from the browser, I receive these characters:

```
GIF87a½€ÿÿÿ,½þ„©Ëí£œ´Ú‹³Þ¼û†âH–æ‰Ádk
ÇòòµuÏú>æùôãEX¯–Š¨²µ‚‰"<}O)Ò¨¬:kÜ'Õª]þ¢`ìc
­Ú”ìvöhe;Ï]¸;oßÂyþ|Þ‡µe§'hÄÔdhW÷§H#&gö¨ð…G™Gy(‰ x÷j†øyÙˆI8uJZZiª
™ªÚº¹i  {ç‰Zj™ˆwšµ7
©;é›9Æy¤VÄ$ú;œË›ÙÛI¬,œ=}|,l¼ÛË§¸ìæ%]h~n»8»ÌíIv—Fe6¿‹¸®0YÉ
J7k8”•pÕá C¬4Èráâ;zü2¤È‘$Kš
```

Can I retrieve GIF format with these characters?

Comment: You're printing binary information as text.

Comment: you have to receive it as binary. this is just a text representation of the binary data and you can not make gif out of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answers.
I've tried a way and I found the Issue

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Accept = "text/html, text/plain";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream, true, false));
bmp.Save("image.gif");
```

Answer (score 8):

A GIF is a binary file. You shouldn't be reading it as a string. Read the GIF into a `byte[]`, and then save those bytes to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
string url = "http://address.com/getFile?s=1234";
string filePath = @"c:\MyFolder\file.gif";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
}
```

and do not forget to add this at the beginning:

```
using System.Net;
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what I know about file formats and the web, the characters are representations ASCII or another encoding of binary.  You may still be able to save it using the [BinaryWriter.Write() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx).